# MICE number of multiply imputed data sets.

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I have multiple questions regarding the utility of the number of multiply imputed data sets "m". What I understood is that mice will repeat the process of imputation of the missing values in the data set m times.

1) Does mice consider the imputation of the previous step and thus each step approaches an eventual convergence or each step are totally independent of each other?

2) If each step are independent of each other, what is the point to have multiple imputed data sets for an imputation purpose?

In the paper explaining mice, there is a scheme showing multiple imputation steps [image]

I guess that the more we have of imputed data set the best is when we want to pool the results, however the analysis results step implies to create a predictive model which could be:

```
#build predictive model
fit <- with(data = imp, lm(y ~ x + z))
```

What happens if in my data set I don't have any predictive column or labels? Indeed my data set contains genomics measurements, and they are all independent.  How can I pool the results, or combine the m imputed data sets without going through a prediction step?

Best,

Babas

Comment: What kind of analysis do you want to do after imputing the dataset multiple times? If the `pool()` function does not support your analysis, then you can pool your results manually using Rubin's rules after running the analysis on each imputed dataset.

Comment: I am analyzing different imputation methods for  micro array data, so my idea is to randomly insert Nan values in my data set and check the distance between the imputed value and the real value. That is why I don't know what to do with the m imputed data set. Should I do a mean of it?

Comment: In short, I am not sure. 

The purpose of multiple imputation is to do the analysis and pool the results, while also considering the uncertainty of the imputed values in the analysis. The purpose is not to end up with one correct complete dataset.

Taking the mean of all imputed sets is a way of pooling these sets, which would be the same as making a model with just an intercept and pooling the results. Another way could be to compare the imputed value with the actual value in each imputed set separately, and then pool these comparisons.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, Indeed I had a miss understanding about multiple imputation "Multiple imputation provides a useful strategy for dealing with data sets with missing values. Instead of filling in a
single value for each missing value, Rubin’s (1987) multiple
imputation procedure replaces each missing value with a
set of plausible values that represent the uncertainty about
the right value to impute."

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: to 1) yes each imputed dataset is independent of each other (at least in the sense you mean it)  about 2) The overall point is account for the uncertainty that comes with the imputation. You would create your m imputed datasets and then perform your analysis on each imputed dataset (m-times). So that you can in the end give some confidence interval where the result could lie in between. Depending on what kind of analysis or next step you are planning after imputation multiple imputation can make sense or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite good, that you have these questions. Multiple imputation is very often misunderstood. It is more a whole concept on how to perform analysis with missing data than a algorithm that just gives you one dataset without missing values.

1) Does mice consider the imputation of the previous step and thus each step approaches an eventual convergence or each step are totally independent of each other?

No there is no convergence. None of the m imputed dataset has  "better" imputed values.

2) If each step are independent of each other, what is the point to have multiple imputed data sets for an imputation purpose?

The whole point is to model the uncertainty of the imputation process. If a NA value is replaced in one imputed dataset with e.g. just 5 this is never the whole truth...a more accurate statement would be maybe something like this: The value is probably somewhere between 4 and 6 ....

This paper of Rubin is a interesting read: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291635